# Regex Pattern match replaceFirst not replacing

Tags: regex

Need help. Somehow can't make this to work. Need to replace the email address value. See `assert`.

```
String line = "John,Smith,123 Main St,Lake City,AB,37221,john.smith@gmail.com,";
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("(^[A-Za-z0-9.'_%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$)",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(line);
String newLine =  mtch.replaceFirst("abc@gmail.com");
assertEquals("John,Smith,123 Main St,Lake City,AB,37221,abc@gmail.com,", newLine);
```

Comment: which language?

Comment: But your string literal is corrupt. Use double escapes and remove anchors.

Comment: just remove ^ and $ from the pattern

Comment: Thanks! That work

Comment: I did not see a post/answer by @SolidSnake to accept. Can I accept or upvote a comment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fix it by using double escapes and removing anchors:

```
s.replaceFirst("[A-Za-z0-9.'_%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}", "abc@gmail.com")
                ^                                ^^             ^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Snyk5s/1)

The `^` matches the start of string position, and `$` matches the end of string. They prevented your regex from matching. Besides, to define a backslash in a Java string literal, one must use 2 backslashes.

Since in Java regex the shorthand classes like `\w` are not Unicode aware by default, you may shorten the pattern:

```
s.replaceFirst("[\\w.'%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}", "abc@gmail.com")
```

If you want to use the current app logic:

```
String line = "John,Smith,123 Main St,Lake City,AB,37221,john.smith@gmail.com,";
Pattern ptn = Pattern.compile("[\\w.'%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}");
Matcher mtch = ptn.matcher(line);
String newLine =  mtch.replaceFirst("abc@gmail.com");
assertEquals("John,Smith,123 Main St,Lake City,AB,37221,abc@gmail.com,", newLine);
```

#### See the [Java demo online](https://rextester.com/LZJOX10608).

Answer (score 0):

The email you wish to match is in the middle of your string, but your regex is looking to match the whole string from beginning to end. This is because of the '^'  and '$' anchors.

Here's an example with your regex, but no anchors:
https://regex101.com/r/Roe6v6/1

Edit: Note that regex101 doesn't support all regex flavors. When implementing a pattern in you particular language (Java?), make sure you follow correct syntax, as @Wiktor Stribiżew has posted.

Comment: That is not the only problem here.